# Passing multiple values as parameter to teradata view

Tags: teradata

We are trying to pass values from report to teradata view as parameter. How do we  pass multiple values to teradata view ?

`AND (v_fact_xyz in (?) or 'ALL' in (?))`

is the line of code written currently
where ? can be single `value('Abd, EFG(ORM)')` or multiple values like these

The report is working fine with single parameter passed but throws error while passing multiple values

`.net data provider for teradata 110083 error.`
`A Null has been specified as the value for a parameter`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your question is how to pass multiple values to your IN clause, something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyView
WHERE v_fact_xyz IN ('Abd','EFG(ORM)','AnotherValue')
```

If that's the case, one way to do it is using a "split" `UDF` (user-defined function) to convert your parameter string into a format that the `IN` clause supports.  The `IN` clause can take record-sets or a single value, but not a comma-separated list.

This page may give you some ideas:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153409/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/031004-1.shtml

Also check to see if Teradata offers any built-in "split" or "delimited" `UDFs` which you can use to do this.